# Simple form input collection that takes in an array and displays as checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

My Model:

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :projects, Array
end
```

Simple form input:

```
= simple_form_for @inquiry, :html => {:id => 'myform', :class => 'fs-form fs-form-full', :autocomplete => 'off'} do |f|

   f.input :projects, collection: projects_collection, as: :check_boxes, label: false
```

In my helper:

```
  def projects_collection
    [['responsive website', :resp_website], ['ecommerce website', :ecomm], ['mobile app', :mobile], ['site/app optimization', :optimization]]
  end
```

The issue is no matter what I enter on the form I get:

```
[4] pry(main)> inquiry.projects
=> "---\n- ecomm\n- optimization\n- ''\n"
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I would use rails form, but the project is already using simple_form.

Would be awesome if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collection-check-boxes - i'm not sure that as: :check_boxes param work without association.

Comment: that didn't work for me, same result

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to set multiple to true

```
f.input :projects, collection: projects_collection, as: :check_boxes, input_html: { multiple: true }, label: false
```